# Brush Texture is a different color when painted on my mesh

Tags: texturing, texture-painting

I have a brush texture that looks like this:

[image: My brush texture]

However, when I try to paint it onto my mesh, this happens:

[image: The Problem]

The background color is clearly not correct, even though I made sure that the Brush Texture and the Canvas Texture had the same hexadecimal orange color. What am I doing wrong?
Here are my settings for brush I am using.

[image: First Settings]
[image: Second Settings]
[image: Third Settings]

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 3):

Choose *Blend > Mix*, and choose a white color, these are the 2 reasons why your texture is not printed as it is:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much!